# How to exit dbshell (SQLite 3) on the command line when using Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, sqlite, sqlite-shell

How do I exit dbshell (SQLite 3) on the command line when using Django?

It's my first time to use the command. I watch a book and am practicing Django at the same time. After I run this command, I have no idea how to leave the environment since I have never learned SQL before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The exit key is determined by what SQL back end you're running.

If it's SQLite 3, like this question, it should be `quit`.

If it's [PostgreSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), like my case, it's `\q`.

Answer (score 3):

You can type **.exit** in thew shell to exit. For more information about commands, type *.help*.

It raises an error and exits ... it was helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

You may use '`.quit`' to exit the SQLite shell. Please mind the *dot* in front.

More reference from here: [SQLite CLI](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just typing *quit* does the work.

Answer (score 1):

You can just hit the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

**These commands below** work on **Windows** to exit **SQLite** and **django dbshell's SQLite**:

```
.exit
```

Or:

```
.quit
```

But **these commands below** without **a dot** don't work on **Windows** to exit **SQLite** and **django dbshell's SQLite**:

```
exit
```

Or:

```
quit
```